# Prove that $1835^{1910} + 1986^{2061}$ is divisible by 7.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $1835^{1910} + 1986^{2061}$ is divisible by 7.
So far I have that $1835=262\times7+1$ and $1986=283\times 7+5$. Then I have $1^{1910}+5^{2061} \mod 7$. I am not sure how to implement Fermat's little theorem to finish this. I know the theorem says if p is a prime and n is a positive integer then $p|n^p-n$. I googled the problem and found some answers but none of them said why exactly we use flt.
http://www.thomasbeatty.com/MATH%20PAGES/ARCHIVES%20-%20EXAMS/Number%20Theory/10%20S%20Num%20Theory%20Test%202B%20-%20solutions.pdf

Comment: Why do you need to use FLT? Once you know that $1835\equiv 1986 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ then it just become simple computing of $5^n \pmod 7$ for $n\ge 1$. This shoud be a cycle of $5\to 4 \to 6\to 2\to 3\to 1\to 5$

Comment: Hint: $2061=6*343+3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lil' Fermat* says that if $n\not\equiv 0\mod 7$, $n^6\equiv 1\mod 7$, so that $n^k\equiv n^{k\bmod 6}\mod 7$.

So, here,
$$1835^{1910}+1986^{2061}\equiv 1+5^3\equiv 1+(-2)^3\equiv 1-8\equiv1-1=0\mod 7.$$

Comment: I just about understand why US mathematicians find it cute to talk about "Baby Rudin". But taken together with "Lil' Fermat" the vision of a Disney movie full of odious mathematical prodigies in their infancy is just too puke-making. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Very smart! Actually, in my case , it  refers to an old comic strip from the thirties, Lil' Abner. As to odious mathematical prodigies, I'd rather imagine  some TeX Avery's cartoon…

Comment: @Rob It get's better: $\mu\rm Fermat$, and Gosper's milli-Ramanujan scale, etc. The sky is the limit...

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: you should propose it to the maintainer of the `siunitx` package ;o)

Answer (score 1):

$1^{1910} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$

$5^{2061} \equiv 5^3 \pmod 7$ since $(5^6)^{343} = 5^{2058} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$

$7 \mid 126$

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple because we can prove by,

$1835\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$
and

$1986\equiv 5 \pmod{7}$
Because $1^{1910}+5^{2061}\equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ is prove.